# Why doesn't my Compute Stick boot to a live USB?

Tags: linux, boot, debian, liveusb, clonezilla

I'm trying to boot a newer-generation Intel Compute Stick to a live persistent Linux USB stick so I can clone the Compute Stick's hard drive to an .img file for later use. I don't want to use Clonezilla, because I need to create an application that will reside on the USB stick.

The problem I have is this: the Compute Stick will *only* boot to a Clonezilla live stick. I've tried Ubuntu, Debian, and Puppy Linux. I've tried using `dd` to burn the .iso to the stick, I've tried unzipping the .iso to the stick using `7z`, and I've tried `mkusb`. No matter what I've tried, it doesn't show up in the boot menu as a bootable item. Only the Clonezilla image works. Using the command line in Clonezilla shows that it's running Debian 4.6, but I tried that version of Debian as well with no luck.

Can anyone fill me in as to what the Clonezilla live image has that I don't?

Comment: UEFI or CSM enabled?

Comment: UEFI enabled. Secure boot disabled.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else comes across this, the answer is simple: press F2 to enter the BIOS settings and set the OS you're going to install (even if you're not actually going to install anything) to 'Android'. Then the live USB shows up as a bootable device.

Comment: For me I had one of the Atom x5-Z8330 sticks, which is a 32-bit part.  Wouldn't boot a 64-bit Debian USB stick no matter what I tried :)

Comment: I just changed mine from Windows 32 to Windows 64 and Ubuntu booted up off of a USB stick.  Thanks!